# Dynamic Pivot Table With Independent Indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with basic sociodem variables and a number of other covariates. For the sociodem variables, I want to create a pivot table so the two columns are aggregated by `Test Result`. I want some variables categorized by count and some by median. For example, I want to capture the median for `WBC` but I want the count by `Race`.

I am unsure how to structure my pivot or groupby tables as I know the column needs to be `Test Result` and the index's need to be the other covariates, but I can't have multiple indexes as different variables.

```
Example Dataframe
ID    Race    WBC_Count  Cough  (0/1)  Test Result....
1     black     23.6       0                Positive 
2     white     13.5       1                Negative
3     hispanic  20.3       0                Positive

               Positive Negative 
Black             23        54
White             23        56
Asian             34        18
...
WBC(median)      13.5       10.9
Cough(count)     23          13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the desired column(s).
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with different functions for different columns
- *I know the column needs to be Test Result and the index's need to be the other covariates, but I can't have multiple indexes as different variables.*

  - [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) on a specific level to remove a multi-index.
- The sample data provided in the question is not easily reproducible as posted, so a reproducible dataset has been provided for this answer.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# sample data
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
data = {'a': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(25)],
        'groups': [random.choice(['1-5', '6-25', '26-100', '100-500', '500-1000', '>1000']) for _ in range(25)],
        'treatment': [random.choice(['Yes', 'No']) for _ in range(25)],
        'date': pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=25).tolist()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
 a  groups treatment       date
 2   >1000       Yes 2020-07-20
 4  26-100       Yes 2020-07-21
 1   >1000       Yes 2020-07-22
 5    6-25        No 2020-07-23
 2  26-100       Yes 2020-07-24

# groupby and aggregate different features of different columns
df.groupby(['groups', 'treatment']).agg({'a': 'mean', 'groups': 'count'}).reset_index(level='treatment')

         treatment         a  groups
groups                              
1-5             No  5.000000       3
1-5            Yes  7.000000       1
100-500         No  5.500000       2
100-500        Yes  3.000000       2
26-100          No  9.000000       1
26-100         Yes  2.666667       3
500-1000        No  2.666667       3
500-1000       Yes  7.500000       2
6-25            No  5.500000       2
6-25           Yes  5.333333       3
>1000          Yes  2.000000       3
```